# Scrollbar appears in IE11 when floating links to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with my CSS in IE 11. I'm trying to float some links to the right but when the screen hits a certain width, the links stay where they are and causes a scrollbar to appear and a lot of white.

[Here's the site](http://www.diychatroom.com) (look at the footer) The site isn't responsive ready, but I'd like to at least get the links to scoot over with the width of the browser if possible.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of IE11]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links aren't moving over (and a scrollbar is appearing) because there is a set width on the container within the footer

```
.container-custom {
  width: 1250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You could try changing this to be:

```
.container-custom {
  width: 80%; // Or some other arbitrary value that won't be fixed
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

that way it will still remain centered, but expand and contract fluidly.

Answer (score 1):

In your footer you have a child div (container-custom) which has CSS `.container-custom {width:1250px; margin:0 auto;}.`

You need to set that width to your main width.
`

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks for your help!